# 3 post positions (configuring query args)

Tags: php, wordpress

Im new here and need some help. I have three post loops positions in my theme. 
My first loop display sticky post or the last post:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'      => 1,
    'post__in'            => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
);
 query_posts($args);
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
$thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' );
?>

<div id="toppost">
<div class="imagebg">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<div class="topimage" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('<?php echo $img_url ?>')"></div>
</a>
<div id="overimg">
<div class="kategorias">
<?php the_category('', ', ', ''); ?>
</div>

<div class="toptitle">
<h2>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); /*3*/ ?>
</a>
</h2>
</div>

<div class="entrycontent">
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
</div>

</div>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?> 
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**And here is the problem:** On the second position i want display last post, but only when the sticky post in on the first position. Second position should disappear when there is no sticky post.

Actual my second loop:

```
<?php
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
                $args=array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'caller_get_posts'=> 0,
                'paged' => $paged,
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
                );
 query_posts($args); 
if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
$thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' );
?>

<div id="contentwrap">

<div id="topsticky">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<div class="topimagesticky" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $img_url ?>')"></div>
</a>

<div id="overimgsticky">

<div class="kategoriasticky">
<?php the_category('', ', ', ''); ?>
</div>

<div class="toptitlesticky">
<h2>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_title(); /*3*/ ?>
</a>
</h2>
</div>

<div class="entrycontent">
 <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?> 
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Third loop display couple of post. Loop start from second newest post. I've done that, just offset the first post:

```
$args=array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'posts_per_page' => 1,
                    'showposts' => 10,
                    'offset' => 1,
                                        /* 'category__not_in' => 22, */
                );`
```

Im looking for solution to display last post on second position only when sticky is on first position. In other situatuion second position disappear.

Comment: Show more code, please.  How are you displaying the sticky post?  Do you have a loop? Show that loop, and any code you've used to try and get the last post (the second loop)

Comment: you could do an order by date or post id

Comment: @cale_b edited, more code added

Comment: @ThomasK ok, i can order post by date but second position don't dissapear when there is no sticky post on first loop. In that option on the first and second position is the same, last post.